# Adding an HTML/PHP code segment into <ul> through JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, html-lists

I have images being saved into an uploads/ folder in my main directory through an upload.php file. I want to make it so that if an image successfully uploads to the folder, it is added as an li tag into my index file.

Here's the snippet from index.php

```
<ul>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['filename'];  ?>"></li>
</ul>
```

This is the end of upload.php at which I want the above li element to be added each time it runs through successfully

```
//Upload file
else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". $target_file. " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
}
```

Comment: A better approach would be to save each new filename in a database/xml file/serialized array/anything that can manage data easily and then on your index.php file get that data, loop through it and display each in an `li` tag.

Comment: Make your upload.php json responsive, use an ajax request to see if upload.php echoed correctly and then use javascript to add it to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your filenames as an path to you dir in a database with an index for easy sorting for example with MySQL and after a query and fetching the results to an array you could use an foreach loop with php.

```
$filenames = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM allFiles ORDER BY id DESC");
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($filenames )){
            $filenameArr[] = $row;
          }
```

Then you could use an foreach like:

```
<?php foreach (filenameArr as $k => $v) { ?>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="<?php echo filenameARR[$k]['filename']; ?>"></li>
  </ul>
<?php } ?>
```